# If I've installed an application both as a snap and via APT, how can I tell which one is currently running?

Tags: snap

If I were to install the same application both as a snap and using APT, how would I be able to call each one separately and how would I know which one was running?

I am not yet fully convinced that snap is best for the end-user and want to compare the performance of a few packages.

Comment: You can search the name of the program using [Htop](https://hisham.hm/htop/) (F3 key as the shortcut ) and then see the full path of the binary . If it was like /snap/bin/.... then it's a snap program. Or if you prefer using "ps " , run "ps -ef | grep program "

Comment: If I type `buckle<tab><tab>` to get what options are available, I can see "*buckle               bucklespring.buckle*"  as the result, then if I use `whereis buckle` it responds */usr/games/buckle* telling me it was *deb* package installed.  If I `whereis bucklespring` I get */snap/bin/bucklespring.buckle* telling me it's a snap. (Why I have both I do **not** know!!?).  I could select via path, but don't need to in this case due to name difference..

Comment: Apt isn't a "version", it's a package manager and has nothing to do with this question. (In fact, you can have a Ubuntu system without apt, it wouldn't be very convenient but it's possible)

Comment: No, snap is not only a package manager, it is also a file format (a package) in the same way that deb are also package. apt is a front end for dpkg and repository manager. You can add repositories and your packages would be installed by apt, yet the answers below wouldn't be applicable to those packages. In other words: it's snap repositories vs ubuntu repositories.

Comment: Due to the rollback war between OP and editors (FYI: the edits were beneficial and should have been kept) I have rolled back to the acceptable version with some modifications and **locked this post** for a week to let everyone cool down.  No more activity is accepted on this post in the interim until the lock expires.  Go cool off, everyone.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

**Call each one separately**

You can start a specific version of an application by providing the full path name of the executable. Firefox, e.g., installed using APT will be launched by `/usr/bin/firefox`. The executables of snap applications are under `/snap/bin/` so `/snap/bin/firefox` will launch the snap version.

Typing `firefox` will launch the APT version, because `/usr/bin` is listed earlier in the search path than `/snap/bin` in a default Ubuntu install. The default PATH is:

```
$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
```

When you simply type `firefox`, the system searches each of the consecutive directories (folders) until an executable with the name `firefox` is found. If the APT version is installed, it will find the executable in `/usr/bin` before searching `/snap/bin`, so the search will be stopped and that executable will be launched.

You can learn which executable will be launched with the command `which`.

```
$ which firefox
/usr/bin/firefox
```

You can learn which executables you have installed with the command `whereis`:

```
$ whereis firefox
firefox: /usr/bin/firefox /usr/lib/firefox /etc/firefox /snap/bin/firefox /usr/share/man/man1/firefox.1.gz
```

Here, both the APT and the snap version of firefox are installed.

**Know which one is running**

*Running processes*

The command `ps ax` lists all running processes. Thus:

```
ps ax | grep firefox
```

will list all processes with the name "firefox". The output includes the full pathname of the executable.

*Creator of a specific window*

It is also possible to identify the creator of a specific window, to learn whether the open window is from the APT or the snap version. However, this is rather complicated and not always reliable. See the Unix & Linux Stackexchange questions [What process created this X11 window?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5478/what-process-created-this-x11-window) and [What process created this window with no PID associated?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/46621/what-process-created-this-window-with-no-pid-associated).

Comment: "installed using APT" note, that there are repositories that have versions of programs that don't install binaries on /usr/bin or /bin. Installing using apt doesn't mean that it would always be on the standard directories. (The binaries could reside on /opt or /usr/local)

Comment: `xkill` usually works for me in killing the process that created a particular window or dialog. That said, killing a process and checking logs to see which one it was is a poor way of doing things but works for dev environment use cases.

Comment: This is not true, Chromium installed via sudo apt install chromium, installs a snap, and `which chromium-browser` prints `/usr/bin/chromium-browser`, but it still runs a snap.

Answer (score 11):

Examples using gnome-calculator, which many folks have in both deb and snap formats:

- How to call each one separately: Let's find full paths.

  ```bsh
  $ which -a gnome-calculator     # -a keeps searching after the first hit
  /usr/bin/gnome-calculator
  /snap/bin/gnome-calculator

  $ whereis -b gnome-calculator   # -b returns binaries only
  gnome-calculator: /usr/bin/gnome-calculator /snap/bin/gnome-calculator
  ```
- How to determine which one is running. In this example, BOTH are running. The difference is readily apparent.

  ```bsh
  $ ps -x | grep gnome-calculator
  69445 ?        Sl     0:05 /snap/gnome-calculator/748/usr/bin/gnome-calculator
  69549 pts/0    Sl     0:01 gnome-calculator
  69727 pts/0    S+     0:00 grep --color=auto gnome-calculator

  $ pgrep -af gnome-calculator
  69445 /snap/gnome-calculator/748/usr/bin/gnome-calculator
  69549 gnome-calculator
  ```

Comment: You might better use `pgrep -a` (or `pgrep -af` to match the full command line) instead of piping `ps` and `grep`.